# Question on Morse inequalities

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis, morse-theory

I want to understand why: if i have

[image]

then $(4.1)$ is formal : it means that
[image]

please help me

Thank you

EDIT1: $(4.1)$ tel us that $\displaystyle\sum_{q=0}^{\infty} (M_q-\beta_q)t^q=(1+t)Q(t)$
Whene $t=-1$ we have directly that $\displaystyle\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}(-1)^q M_q=\displaystyle\sum_{q=0}^{\infty} (-1)^q \beta_q$

and wehave also that $\displaystyle\sum_{q=0}^{\infty}(-1)^q M_q\geq\displaystyle\sum_{q=0}^{\infty} (-1)^q \beta_q$ because $Q(t)$ has nonnegative coefficient

but how to obtain that $\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{q}(-1)^{q-j} M_j\geq\displaystyle\sum_{j=0}^{q} (-1)^{q-j} \beta_j$ ???

Answer (score 0):

This is more or less Lemma 3.43 of the book of Banyaga and Hurtubise "Lectures on Morse homology". It is not difficult, I think direct induction should work. They only use real polynomials, but the formal case is not more difficult.